# HTML5 Video not showing in Safari

Tags: html, video

I've read other answers on here regarding this issue but none help. I'm trying to use the HTML5 video in Safari, but it just won't show up at all. For reference view: http://www.shaun-pelling.com/malagnini/index2.html - (the video is found on the slider at the top, just click the slider arrow left once).

It shows up fine in all other browsers but Safari.

htaccess file:

```
<Files ~ "\.(mp4|m4v)">
AddType video/mp4 mp4
order allow,deny
allow from all
satisfy any
</Files>

AddType video/mp4 mp4 m4v
AddType audio/mp4 m4a
AddType video/ogg ogv
AddType audio/ogg ogg oga
AddType video/webm webm
```

HTML Code:

```
<video width="100%" controls="controls">
<source src="/malagnini/video/paradise.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="/malagnini/video/paradise.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
<source src="/malagnini/video/paradise.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

Comment: Plays fine for me - OSX 10.8.3 and Safari, same experience as Chrome. The controls are right at the bottom of the screen rather than overlaid but apart from that there's no problem that I could reproduce

Comment: Yes - it appears that you need Quick Time installed to view videos in Safari on Windows. So this is now solved.

Comment: ah! you'd not mentioned Windows. FWIW Apple have stopped updating Safari for Windows since 5.x

Comment: You shouldn't really use Safari on Windows. It's not supported by Apple any more. If you were installing it to test stuff under Safari, be aware that it doesn't always behave like Mac Safari - so you should ideally test on a real mac (or Mac virtual PC) if you need to do Mac testing.

Answer (score 5):

This is now solved. You need Quick Time installed to view HTML5 videos in Safari when on Windows.